# TypeScript + AngularJS directive: cannot call 'new' on class

Tags: angularjs, typescript, directive

I have some issue with declaring a class. I have the following code:

```
module Directive.toast{
    import ToastService = Toaster.ToasterService;
    'use strict';

    interface IToastScope extends ng.IScope {
        message:string;
        display:boolean
    }

    class ToastDirective implements ng.IDirective {
        templateUrl= '/toast.html';
        restrict= 'AE';
        replace= true;
        scope = {
        };

        public message:any;
        public display:boolean;

        constructor(public Toast:ToastService, public $timeout:angular.ITimeoutService) {

        }

        link:ng.IDirectiveLinkFn = (scope:IToastScope, element:ng.IAugmentedJQuery, attributes:ng.IAttributes) => {
            scope.message = this.Toast.message.text;
            this.$timeout(function() {
                this.message.display= false;
                element.remove();
            }, 5000);
        };

        static factory():ng.IDirectiveFactory {
            return () => new ToastDirective();
        }
    }

    var app = AppModule.getModule();
    app.directive('toast', ToastDirective.factory());
}
```

Which gives me an error:

```
error TS2346: Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.
```

However, if I delete the injections from the constructor, it will pass through the compiler - but I do need to inject those dependencies, to use them in the linking functions to the directive. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this;

```
export var ToastDirective = (public Toast:ToastService, public $timeout:angular.ITimeoutService) : angular.IDirective =>
{
    return {
         templateUrl: '/toast.html',
         restrict: 'AE',
         replace: true,
         scope: {
             message: "=",
             display: "="
         },
         link: (scope: IToastScope, element:angular.IAugmentedJQuery, attributes: angular.IAttributes) => {
             scope.message = Toast.message.text;
             $timeout(()=> {
                 scope.message.display=false;
                 element.remove();
             }, 5000);
         }
    }

    ToastDirective.$inject = ["ToastService", "$timeout"];

    var app = AppModule.getModule();

    app.directive('toast', ToastDirective);
}
```